# I have multiple <td> with the checkbox and its values.I want to change colour of <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is my HTML code which contains multiple checkboxes with the respective values in `<td>`. I got the values of clicked checkboxes through php which is an array format `$res[]`. I want to make the  checkbox disappear of which i got values and make the `<td>` background color to red with the value of checkbox visible. I got the values of checkboxes in php as `$res[0][seat]=>4;` and `$res[1][seat]=>1` where 4 and 1 are values. How to do this using jQuery?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input name="chk" class='chk' type="checkbox" value="1"/>
            <label>1</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td >
            <input name="chk" class='chk' type="checkbox" value="2"/>
            <label>2</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td >
            <input name="chk" class='chk' type="checkbox" value="3"/>
            <label>3</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td >
            <input name="chk" class='chk' type="checkbox" value="4"/>
            <label>4</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED** try this:

```js
var arr=[4,1];// array list received from php 
for(i=0;i< arr.length;i++){
$('table tbody tr td input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
  if($(this).val()==arr[i]){
    $(this).hide();
      $(this).closest('td').css('background-color','red');
  }else if($(this).is(':visible')){
   $(this).closest('td').css('background-color','pink');
  }
 }); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table><tr><td>
<input name="chk" class='chk' type="checkbox" value="1"/>
<label>1</label>
</td></tr>
<tr><td >
<input name="chk" class='chk' type="checkbox" value="2"/>
<label>2</label>
</td></tr>
<tr><td >
<input name="chk" class='chk' type="checkbox" value="3"/>
<label>3</label>
 </td></tr>
<tr><td >
<input name="chk" class='chk' type="checkbox" value="4"/>
<label>4</label>
 </td></tr></table>
```

Comment: how to get those php array which are dynamic in javascript array

Comment: @curious2lrn if you are expecting the on page load then use var arr=<?php echo $phparr ?>; but for this your page should be .php or .html not .js. or make ajax call.

Comment: i am running a while loop ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){$res[]=$row; } i have stored it in $res[] so that i can use it outside while loop so how to store that $res[0][seat](multiple values) in javascript array

Comment: @ same page with .php extension

Comment: why you are using key seat in $res[0][seat]. if you can use $res[0]=4,$res[1]=1 then do this: in document.ready part var arr=<? echo $res?>; then rest of the code what i have written.

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [seat] => 1
            [bname] => Hindustan Volvo
        )
         [1] => Array
        (
            [seat] => 4
            [bname] => Hindustan Volvo
        )
} column name is seat and i want bname too.when i get multiple values it gets overwritten

Comment: i have done a bit of research and got it. thanks a ton. just done these changes to your code                                                 var narr=<?php echo json_encode($res); ?>;
var arr=JSON.stringify(narr);

Comment: you should be doing JSON.parse(narr) not stringify, stringify will give entire data in string format.

Comment: JSON.parse(narr) is not working .i'll stick with the first one.anyways thanks

Comment: could you help me out in one thing i want to highlight the other checkboxes with value (the values which are not clicked)in pink color

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.chk').on('click', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).closest('td').css('background-color','red');
    }
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/j37yaovs/)

Answer (score 0):

use **[filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** in jquery

```
var arrayValue = [4, 1];
$(".chk").filter(function () {
    return arrayValue.indexOf(+this.value) != -1  // check arrayvalue is present in check box or not using indexOf
}).closest("td").css('background-color', 'red').find(".chk").hide();   // set background for closest td and hide chk
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ucg6v1v0/4/)**

Comment: i am running a while loop ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){$res[]=$row; } i have stored it in $res[] so that i can use it outside while loop so how to store that $res[0][seat](multiple values) in javascript array